# Export from "main" must be a function that returns an HTML string

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, css-modules, static-generator

I was following every step from this article about Static Site Generator https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-3-react/. The only thing i change from that article is the setting for .babelrc . On presets i use es2015 instead of es2016 and it looks like this

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets" : ["es2015","react"]
}
```

In the i got this following error

```
ERROR in Error: Export from "main" must be a function that returns an HTML string
```

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the preset first, before you can use it.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

I can't post comments yet, so I apologize if this doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I had installed it before. It was explained on the previous series here https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-2-getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

It's an issue with `static-site-generator-webpack-plugin`.

Look at the issue [here](https://github.com/markdalgleish/static-site-generator-webpack-plugin/issues/46). It should help you!